# Extract org.restlet.http.headers value from Camel headers inside a .choice()

Tags: apache, apache-camel, restlet

I'm trying to extract a value from org.restlet.http.headers header collection in a Camel route.

My incoming POST has a http header property called IncomingRequestType: ABCD.
Camel moves this inside the exchange headers collection, but it is buried inside org.restlet.http.headers which is in-itself a collection of headers.

I can extract the value in a process using the code below:

```
.process(new Processor() {
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
      org.restlet.util.Series<Header> httpHeaders = null;
      httpHeaders = (Series<Header>) exchange.getIn().getHeader("org.restlet.http.headers");
      String reqType = httpHeaders.getValues("IncomingRequestType").toString();
}})
```

Outside of a process I need to access the IncomingRequestType inside a .choice().when()

e.g. i want to be able to do:

```
.choice()
    .when(header("org.restlet.http.headers")["IncomingRequestType"]).isEqualTo("ABCD"))
```

Any suggestions on how this can be done. I've tried creating predicates but cannot get a suitable solution.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in the [simple language](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html):

```
.choice()
    .when(simple("${in.header.org.restlet.http.headers[IncomingRequestType]} == 'ABCD'"))
```

Comment: I dont think it will work. I tried and it searches for header named "org.restlet.http.headers[IncomingRequestType]"